# Hardhat cannot console.log msg.data

Tags: ethereum, solidity, hardhat

```
fallback() external {
        console.log(msg.data);  
        (bool result, ) = address(delegate).delegatecall(msg.data);
        if (result) {
            console.log("SUCESS");
            this;
        }
}
```

returns

```
TypeError: Member "log" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(library console).
        console.log(msg.data);
        ^---------^
```

is there a restriction on what kind of data that can be console.logged?
what does argument-dependent lookup even mean?

Answer (score 13):

the hardhat console library has other functions for different data types. msg.data is calldata so it will be bytes. try console.logBytes(msg.data);

here is the code for console.sol: https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat/blob/master/packages/hardhat-core/console.sol